# Where does the pattern occur in a match by find?

Tags: find

The manpage of `find` says:

> -name
>
> Base of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading  directories
>                 removed)

```
$ find ~ -name bookmark | less
```

returns nothing, while

```
$ find ~ -name bookmarks | less
./.streamtuner/cache/bookmarks
./.config/zathura/bookmarks
./.elinks/bookmarks
```

has three matches.

Why does the first not have the matches of the second?

If I would like to find those files whose names contain `bookmark` regardless the position of `bookmark` in the filename, how should I use `find`? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The pattern given to [`-name` has to match the *entire* base filename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05). The behaviour of the `-name` pattern is defined as:

> The primary shall evaluate as true if the basename of the current pathname matches pattern

This means it's true when the whole of the basename matches the [pattern](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) you gave. You can think of a pattern as being basically like a shell glob: you can use `*`, `?`, and `[...]` patterns inside it, with the start and end of the pattern aligned with the start and end of the string.

So your command:

```
find ~ -name bookmarks
```

finds files named "bookmarks" because that is the entire filename, but:

```
find ~ -name bookmark
```

would only find files named 'bookmark', because there are no wildcard characters in the pattern.

To match files called both `bookmark` and `bookmarks`, you could use:

```
find ~ -name 'bookmark*'
```

So if you want to find

> those files whose names contain bookmark regardless the position of bookmark in the filename

you can use use:

```
find ~ -name '*bookmark*'
```

to match files whose names have any number of characters, then `bookmark`, then any number of characters.

Comment: +1. I'd just add that the single quote around the pattern are mandatory, as otherw ise the shell itself would try to expand them, therefore sometimes (when it matches something in the current dir) changing it into something else. (And if you really want just files, add `-type f` after the `~ `)

Answer (score 1):

Argument of `-name` parameter in `find` command works exactly as wildcard characters in file/directory names in command line. * is any string and ? is any character.

Comment: Yes and no. If you type something like `ls *.c` at the command prompt, it's the *shell* that expands `*.c` and `ls` is given the list of such files as its arguments (e.g., `ls` thinks you typed `ls file1.c file2.c ... file100.c`). The exact same thing happens with `find`: `find . -name *.c` expands to `find . -name file1.c file2.c ... file100.c` and this isn't what you want: `find` will complain that `file2.c` isn't a valid option. Therefore, when using `find`, you must do `find . -name '*.c'` (or similar) so that `find` sees the wildcard, instead of the shell expanding it.